# graph with ggplot improve scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a plot look like 'example.png'. suggestions to set the x-axis scale? And how to draw the diagonals so that they mark divisors of % increase?
thank you

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)


mpd2020=data.frame(
'Pais'=c('Algeria','Argentina','Australia','Austria','Belgium','Brazil','Canada','Chile','China','China, Hong Kong SAR','Colombia','Czechoslovakia','D.P.R. of Korea','Denmark','Egypt','Finland','France','Germany','Indonesia','Iran (Islamic Republic of)','Iraq','Ireland','Italy','Jamaica','Japan','Jordan','Lebanon','Malaysia','Mexico','Morocco','Myanmar','Nepal','Netherlands','New Zealand','Norway','Peru','Philippines','Poland','Portugal','Republic of Korea','Saudi Arabia','South Africa','Spain','Sri Lanka','Sweden','Syrian Arab Republic','Taiwan, Province of China','Thailand','Tunisia','Turkey','United Kingdom','United States','Uruguay','Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)','Viet Nam'),
`PIBpc 1820`=c(685,1591,826,1941,2358,867,1441,824,882,1132,850,1353,752.7256,2031,956,1313,1809,1572,827,877,877,1398,2665.0738,1117,1317,877,1084,961,1007,685,803,641,3006,826,1384,835,931,818,1665.4262,815.7743,797,1188,1600,877,1415,1084,966,909,685,974,3306,2674.048,1983,968,840
),
`PIBpc 2018`=c(14228.025,18556.3831,49830.7993,42988.0709,39756.2031,14033.5656,44868.7435,22104.7654,13101.7064,50839.3714,13545.0495,29600.5982,1596.3517,46312.3442999999,11957.2122,38896.7005,38515.9193,46177.6187,11851.7372,17011.3042,12835.8126,64684.302,34364.1682,7272.9805,38673.8081,11506.3383,12558.9669,24842.3559,16494.079,8451.1355,5838.2173,2727.4238,47474.1095,35336.1363,84580.1362,12310.0847,8139.1395,27455.237,27035.6002,37927.6095,50304.7502,12165.7948,31496.52,11662.9064,45541.8921,3349.4597,44663.8642,16648.6237,11353.8865,19270.2202,38058.0856,55334.7394,20185.836,10709.9506,6814.1423)
)


row.names(mpd2020) <- mpd2020$País

x <- ggplot(mpd2020, aes(x=mpd2020$`PIBpc 1820`, y=mpd2020$`PIBpc 2018`)) +
  geom_point(
    aes(color = mpd2020$País, fill = mpd2020$País),
    size = 2.5, alpha = 0.5) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs(title="Variación PIB per cápita.",
       subtitle = "1820 - 2018. Precios PIB pc 2011",
       x ="PIBpc 1820", y = "PIBpc 2018",
       caption= "Fuente: Maddison Project Database 2020")

y <- x + 
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(label = mpd2020$País),
    family = "Poppins",
    size = 3,
    min.segment.length = 0, 
    seed = 42, 
    box.padding = 0.5,
    max.overlaps = Inf,
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.010, "npc")),
    nudge_x = .15,
    nudge_y = .5,
    color = "grey50"
  ) 

y + geom_abline()
```

Comment: If you're trying to do log scales, just use `scale_x_log10`. If they're something else, you'll need to specify

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point. I have chosen `coord_fixed` to get the same ratio for the axis - that looks better and comes closer to the plot in your link above.

A separate DF was created for the annotations of the `geom_line`s.

Additional variables were created and added to the original **DF**. Those variables (`two_times`, ..) were used for making the lines.
The **DF** was made longer and subset of this **DF** were used to make the `geom_point`, `geom_line` and `geom_text_`.

The axis were scaled with `scale_..._log10`.

[image]

```r
library(tidyverse)
# library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)


mpd2020 <- data.frame(
  "Pais" = c("Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Brazil", "Canada", "Chile", "China", "China, Hong Kong SAR", "Colombia", "Czechoslovakia", "D.P.R. of Korea", "Denmark", "Egypt", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Lebanon", "Malaysia", "Mexico", "Morocco", "Myanmar", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Norway", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Republic of Korea", "Saudi Arabia", "South Africa", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sweden", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Taiwan, Province of China", "Thailand", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "United Kingdom", "United States", "Uruguay", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", "Viet Nam"),
  `PIBpc 1820` = c(685, 1591, 826, 1941, 2358, 867, 1441, 824, 882, 1132, 850, 1353, 752.7256, 2031, 956, 1313, 1809, 1572, 827, 877, 877, 1398, 2665.0738, 1117, 1317, 877, 1084, 961, 1007, 685, 803, 641, 3006, 826, 1384, 835, 931, 818, 1665.4262, 815.7743, 797, 1188, 1600, 877, 1415, 1084, 966, 909, 685, 974, 3306, 2674.048, 1983, 968, 840),
  `PIBpc 2018` = c(14228.025, 18556.3831, 49830.7993, 42988.0709, 39756.2031, 14033.5656, 44868.7435, 22104.7654, 13101.7064, 50839.3714, 13545.0495, 29600.5982, 1596.3517, 46312.3442999999, 11957.2122, 38896.7005, 38515.9193, 46177.6187, 11851.7372, 17011.3042, 12835.8126, 64684.302, 34364.1682, 7272.9805, 38673.8081, 11506.3383, 12558.9669, 24842.3559, 16494.079, 8451.1355, 5838.2173, 2727.4238, 47474.1095, 35336.1363, 84580.1362, 12310.0847, 8139.1395, 27455.237, 27035.6002, 37927.6095, 50304.7502, 12165.7948, 31496.52, 11662.9064, 45541.8921, 3349.4597, 44663.8642, 16648.6237, 11353.8865, 19270.2202, 38058.0856, 55334.7394, 20185.836, 10709.9506, 6814.1423)
)
row.names(mpd2020) <- mpd2020$País
df <- mpd2020 |>
  mutate(
    two_times = PIBpc.1820 * 2, 
    ten_times = PIBpc.1820 * 10, 
    fifty_times = PIBpc.1820 * 50
  )

#| create a Df for annotations at lines
df_anno <- tibble(
  x = 1800, y = c(18000, 3600, 90000),
  label = c(
    "10 times more",
    "2 times",
    "50 times"
  )
)

#| make DF long
ddf <- df |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Pais, PIBpc.1820))

ggplot(ddf[ddf$name == "PIBpc.2018", ], aes(x = `PIBpc.1820`, y = value)) +
  geom_point(
    aes(color = Pais, fill = Pais),
    size = 2.5, alpha = 0.5
  ) +
  geom_line(
    data = ddf[ddf$name != "PIBpc.2018", ],
    aes(y = value, group = name),
    color = "grey", linetype = "dashed"
  ) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  scale_x_log10() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(
    title = "Variación PIB per cápita.",
    subtitle = "1820 - 2018. Precios PIB pc 2011",
    x = "PIBpc 1820", y = "PIBpc 2018",
    caption = "Fuente: Maddison Project Database 2020"
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = ddf[ddf$name == "PIBpc.2018", ],
    aes(x = PIBpc.1820, y = value, label = Pais),
    max.overlaps = getOption("ggrepel.max.overlaps", default = 15), size = 2
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = df_anno,
    aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, angle = 45),
    vjust = -1, color = c("green", "gray", "gray")
  ) +
  coord_fixed(ylim = c(1500, 92000))
#> Warning: ggrepel: 12 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider
#> increasing max.overlaps
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is very good, the graph is very good

Comment: Be aware of the warning at the end of the listing: the names of 12 countries are missing from the plot. Your attempt to use `geom_abline()` was correct, but I think there is a bug in 'ggplot2' that "breaks" `geom_abline()` when log scales are used, except for the case of slope = 1. 
The Maddison databate data can be downloded at: (https://www.rug.nl/ggdc/historicaldevelopment/maddison/releases/maddison-project-database-2020?lang=en).
R pckage 'maddison', available in CRAN contains the 2018 release of the database, which uses a different methodology.